# How to simply draw matts for pupils writing Chinese character?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want realize the effect like the following picture:

[image]

but I can only draw the picture like this:

[image]

Are there any simple methods drawing these matts?

```
 \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pinyin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dash pattern=on 2.2pt off 2.2pt](0,0)grid[step=0.5](1,1);
                    \draw[thick](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
                    \node at (0.5,1.3){\ping4};                  
\draw[dash pattern=on 2.2pt off 2.2pt](1.2,0)grid[step=0.5](2.2,1);
                    \draw[thick](1.2,0)rectangle(2.2,1);
                    \node at (1.7,1.3){\ba2};
\draw[dash pattern=on 2.2pt off 2.2pt](2.6,0)grid[step=0.5](3.6,1);
                    \draw[thick](2.6,0)rectangle(3.6,1);
                    \node at (3.1,1.3){\chuan2};
\draw[dash pattern=on 2.2pt off 2.2pt](3.8,0)grid[step=0.5](4.8,1);
                    \draw[thick](3.8,0)rectangle(4.8,1);
                    \node at (4.3,1.3){\dai4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems like a good use of the `\pic` syntax in TikZ, to draw one grid and then repeat it as required.  Alternatively you could draw one grid as a tikzpicture and reuse that.  You method is heavily reliant on hand-positioned coordinates; a benefit of either of the methods I suggest would be freeing you up from that

Comment: @Chris  But I need "pinyin" on the center of the grid top. How to realize that effect when I repeat using the same picture?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest create one picture and repeat it in a table. To change the size change the scaling of `\tikz`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{body={15cm,20cm}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pinyin}
\newcommand\matt[1]{%
  \tikz[scale=0.5]{%
    \draw[dashed,thin](0,0)grid(2,2);
    \draw[thick](0,0)rectangle(2,2);
    \node[anchor=south] at (1,2){\strut#1};
  }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2}\\
  \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2}\\
  \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2}\\
  \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} & \matt{\ping4} \matt{\ba2} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something's up with the text baselines, but overall I think this is the way to go

Comment: A very good method. However I find the pinyin don't align horizontally. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: I've just noticed they don't align on my answer either, or on the question.

Comment: Changing `[anchor=south]` to `[anchor=base] will fix the text alignment

Comment: I added a `\strut` to get alignment right. I think @ChrisH solution works as well.

Comment: OMG I never knew there was a pinyin package. :D

Comment: @StefanH Perfect, This is exactly the same style as I want to draw

Answer (score 9):

Just to show the `quotes` TikZ library for pics with text, and how to use the `foreach` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\tikzset{
    matt/.pic={
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0.5) -- (1,0.5);
        \draw (0.5,1) node[above] {\tikzpictext};
    }
}

\begin{document}
% Inline use
\tikz\pic["p\`ing"]{matt};
\tikz\pic["b\'a"]{matt};

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0)
    \foreach \couple in {{p\`ing, b\'a}, {chu\'an, d\`ai}} {
        \foreach \matt in \couple {
            pic["\matt"]{matt} ++(1.2,0)
        }
        ++(0.2,0)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pinyin}
\tikzset{
    grid/.pic={
        \draw[dash pattern=on 2.2pt off 2.2pt](0,0)grid[step=0.5](1,1);
        \draw[thick](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {grid};
    \node at (0.5,1.3){\ping4};                  
    \pic at (1.2,0) {grid};
    \node at (1.7,1.3){\ba2};
    \pic at (2.6,0) {grid};
    \node at (3.1,1.3){\chuan2};
    \pic at (3.8,0) {grid};
    \node at (4.3,1.3){\dai4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pinyin]

Comment: This is a simple manual illustration of using `\pic`.  The other answers go further with automating it.

Comment: You helped me solve the problem that my grid can not step correctly, thank you very much.

Comment: I'd been looking for a chance to use `\pic`s anyway -- this was a nice question to try them out on.

Comment: @ChrisH You can add `\node[above] at (0.5,1){\strut#1};` to your `pic` and call it with e.g. `\pic at (0,0) {grid=\ping4};`

Comment: @StefanH, yes, but I saw your answer so just posted what I'd got

Answer (score 5):

Here are the boxes:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox{\rectangle}

\newcommand{\boxme}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,+1);
    \draw[dashed] (0.5,0)--(0.5,1);
    \draw[dashed] (0,0.5)--(1,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in { 0,3,6,9,12}
 \foreach \y in { 0,2,4,6,8}
  {
   \node at (\x,\y) {\boxme{}{}{}{}};
   \node at (\x+1.1,\y) {\boxme{}{}{}{}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a better method drawing the matts, thank you very much.